# Jquery - don't show div (popup) for a week after closing

Tags: jquery, popup

I created this popup with newsletter form, it will show when half of a screen is scrolled and by clicking on X will not show anymore.

Is there any chance I can "tell" to jquery not to show this div for a week  after it was closed on "X" if someone opens the page again?

https://www.centuryparklawgroup.com/popup-dev/

Here's a code:

```
<script src="https://www.centuryparklawgroup.com/wp-content/themes/lawyers-attorneys-child/jquery1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
  function checkShowDiv() {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  if ($(window).scrollTop()  > $(window).height() / 2) {    
  $('.nslttppup:hidden').fadeIn('slow'); //prevent re-fades with :hidden
 }
else {
  $('.nslttppup').hide();
  }
}
$(window).scroll(checkShowDiv);
</script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.closeform').click(function() {
  $(window).unbind('scroll', checkShowDiv);
  $(this).closest('.nslttppup').hide('fast');
  return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: use cookies or localstorage

Comment: You can use localstorage with expired_at and then before to show it just check if this key exist and is expired if yes then show otherwise just ignore it

Comment: ^ however if the user is logged in and you want to guarantee that they don't see it for a week you would have to store something server side as cookies and localstorage can be deleted, and users can be on multiple machines/browsers.

Comment: If the user logs in to your system I assume he will see the popup, so you can add a field to your DB that store the date of the last login (if you don't already have it) and on server side check if a week has passed... then return from the server the desired code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just use cookies or local storage , by example below 
I've just set cookie when clicking  on close so the pupu will not show on scroll after 3 minute (you can set time expiration by number of days or date )

Here I set a variable showPopup on ready , by reading a cookie , if it's present and set to 'no' so your popup wont be shown on scroll

so you code should looks like  (due to stackoverflow snippet security we cant do a snippet here See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yk2co36d/1/) FOR  the whole code )

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yk2co36d/1/) (in this example cookies expires after 3 minute )
also I use [jquery cookie plugin](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js)

```
var showPopup = true;

function checkShowDiv() {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(showPopup) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height() / 2) {
      $('.nslttppup').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      $('.nslttppup').hide();
    }
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  showCookieExist();
  $(window).scroll(checkShowDiv);
  $('.closeform').click(function() {
    $(window).unbind('scroll', checkShowDiv);
    $(this).closest('.nslttppup').hide('fast');
    $.cookie('showpopup','no');
    showPopup = false;
    return false;
  });
});

function showCookieExist() {
  console.log($.cookie('showpopup'));
  return $.cookie('showpopup');
}
```